# Add Letters to the Solutions

Tags: wordplay

In each pair of clues, the first clue will give you a word. The second clue will give you a different word comprising the first word, with one letter added, anywhere in the word. For example, clue one gives you "bag" and clue two gives you "b**R**ag". At the end, take all the letters you have added to the second clues. They will give you the answer to "overall clue 1". Then solve "overall clue 2" by adding a letter to the answer to overall clue one.

1 Pound

2 Baby animal

1 Tunnel

2 Desire

1 Wok

2 Hurt

1 Ready

2 Complain

Overall 1 Ship

Overall 2 Fetch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 Pound
2 Baby animal

> lam
> lam**b**

1 Tunnel
2 Desire

> cave
> c**r**ave

1 Wok
2 Hurt

> pan
> pa**i**n

1 Ready
2 Complain

> ripe
> **g**ripe

Overall:
1 Ship
2 Fetch

> brig
>  bri**n**g

Comment: No, you're totally right. I simply made a stupid mistake and didn't double check everything. Will try to fix tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll take a look later

Comment: it's ready. You should get it quickly, then I'll accept

Comment: :) got it but Tim beat me so do what you wish

Comment: Feel free to give D.A.N. the accepted answer, I'm just happy I figured it out. :)

Answer (score 5):

1 Pound
2 Baby animal

> lam
> lamb  -> B

1 Tunnel
2 Desire

> cave
> crave  -> R

1 Wok
2 Hurt

> pan
> pain  -> I

1 Ready
2 Complain

> ripe
> gripe  -> G

Overall 1 Ship
Overall 2 Fetch

> brig
> bring

All those years of playing Sid Meier's Pirates! has finally paid off. :)